# How to make matplotlib cloorbar text position center-aligned?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I visualize my data using Python3 on Windows10 as follows. I try to hide the ticks and tickslabels of colorbar, and plot text inside the colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)

data = 20 + 100*np.random.rand(30, 30) 

#print(data)
plt.imshow(data)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks= [], pad=0.015, aspect=12)

x = 10

for index, label in enumerate([str(np.round(np.amin(data),1)), str(np.round(np.amax(data),1))]):
    
    y = np.amin(data) + 0.1*(np.amax(data) - np.amin(data)) + 0.7*index*(np.amax(data) - np.amin(data))
    
    if index == 0:
        cbar.ax.text(x, y, label, rotation=90, va='center', color='white', fontsize=16)
    else:
        cbar.ax.text(x, y, label, rotation=90, va='center', color='black', fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

It results in

[image]

The text inside the colorbar is misaligned somehow. How to make the text inside the colorbar center-aligned? Is there any suggestion for the value of `x` in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `0.5` as x-position and the [yaxis transform](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) (y-axis in data, x-axis in axes coordinates).

```py
for index, label in enumerate([str(np.round(np.amin(data), 1)), str(np.round(np.amax(data), 1))]):
    y = np.amin(data) + 0.1 * (np.amax(data) - np.amin(data)) + 0.7 * index * (np.amax(data) - np.amin(data))
    cbar.ax.text(0.5, y, label, rotation=90, va='center', ha='center',
                 color='white' if index == 0 else 'black', fontsize=16, transform=cbar.ax.get_yaxis_transform())
```

[image: positioning text in colorbar]